# How can I use ng-repeat in a table body to encompass multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsrender

I'm trying to transition from jsRender to AngularJs and can't seem to figure out how to generate multiple table rows with `ng-repeat`.

I need to generate two table rows per ng-repeat, these rows are related to each other. The second row is actually a hidden row that expands out like an accordion. This works perfectly fine with renderJs:

With renderJs:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stuff</th>
      <th>Stuff2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{for myArray}} <!-- Creates two rows per item in array -->
    <tr>
      <td>{{data}}</td>
      <td>{{data2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="special-row">
      <td>{{otherData}}</td>
      <td>{{otherData2}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/for}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With AngularJs:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stuff</th>
      <th>Stuff2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div ng-repeat="element in myArray"> <!-- This gets removed since it's not a valid element for a table body -->
      <tr>
        <td>{{element.data}}</td>
        <td>{{element.data2}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="special-row">
        <td>{{element.otherData}}</td>
        <td>{{element.otherData2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I cannot have a `<div>` inside of my table body to put the `ng-repeat` on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do it like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Stuff</th>
      <th>Stuff2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="element in myArray">
        <td>{{element.data}}</td>
        <td>{{element.data2}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end class="special-row">
        <td>{{element.otherData}}</td>
        <td>{{element.otherData2}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant. I can't believe I missed that part of the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/feq6pe7m/1/

```
<body ng-app="SampleApp">
  <table ng-controller="fcController" border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Stuff</th>
        <th>Stuff2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="element  in myArray">
      <tr>
        <td>{{element .Data1}}</td>
        <td>{{element .Data2}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="special-row">
        <td>{{element.OtherData1}}</td>
        <td>{{element.OtherData2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This way will generate multiple tbody elements which is bad markup.  In addition, if you have a fixed header and scrolling rows, each tbody is fixed so you loose the row scrolling.  The previous method is a much better way to go.